# Настройка Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Запускаю проект на реальном телефоне. В процессе инсталляции APK выпал шнур. Как заставить Android Studio  в этом случае при повторном нажатии на кнопку "Run" не делать полную очистку и пересборку проекта? Почему она просто не возьмёт готовый APK и не попытается заново его установить? то же касается, если подключить другой телефон.

Comment: Я не знаю, как это можно сделать, но можно повысить скорость сборки проекта(APK). У меня сборка идет за 5-6 секунд. Раньше, 12-18 секунд. [ссылка] (https://medium.com/@101/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed#.th5ghh3hr)

Comment: У меня комп 2008 года выпуска, полная сборка идёт минут 5. Всё, что нашёл в поиске насчет ускорения сборки - я уже сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Процесс работает таким образом, что обрабатывает только тот файл, который был изменен, так что все что можно для вас уже сделано.